# download file with redirect login C#

Tags: c#, http, webclient

I have to download a file from https://cddis.nasa.gov/archive/gnss/data/daily/
it will redirect to the login page and I tried this code but it not working.

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
CookieAwareWebClient http = new CookieAwareWebClient(cookieJar);

string postData = "name=****&password=****6&submit=submit";
string response = http.UploadString("https://urs.earthdata.nasa.gov/oauth/authorize?client_id=gDQnv1IO0j9O2xXdwS8KMQ&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fcddis.nasa.gov%2Fproxyauth&state=aHR0cDovL2NkZGlzLm5hc2EuZ292L2FyY2hpdmUvZ25zcy9kYXRhL2RhaWx5Lw",postData);

// validate your login! 

http.DownloadFile("https://cddis.nasa.gov/archive/gnss/data/daily/2021/brdc/brdc1170.21n.gz", "brdc.21n.gz");
```

this is my CookieAwareWebClient class:

```
class CookieAwareWebClient: WebClient
{
    public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; set; }
    public Uri Uri { get; set; }

    public CookieAwareWebClient()
        : this(new CookieContainer())
    {
    }

    public CookieAwareWebClient(CookieContainer cookies)
    {
        this.CookieContainer = cookies;
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        if (request is HttpWebRequest)
        {
            (request as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = this.CookieContainer;
        }
        HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)request;
        httpRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        return httpRequest;
    }

    protected override WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(request.ToString());
        WebResponse response = base.GetWebResponse(request);
        String setCookieHeader = response.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.SetCookie];

        if (setCookieHeader != null)
        {
            //do something if needed to parse out the cookie.
            if (setCookieHeader != null)
            {
                Cookie cookie = new Cookie(); //create cookie
                this.CookieContainer.Add(cookie);
            }
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

finally, I can't download and get an error System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.'
I still don't understand my problem and how can I fix it?
thanks

Comment: The error 500 is on the server side after the connection completed while trying to process the request.  The server does not like the request.  Either you are sending (or missing) a parameter/header or the value of something is corrupt with the request.   From what I see posted the most likely reason for the error is the parameters on the URL after the question mark.  The cookie could be bad or outdated.  So you may try to manually delete the cookie and try again.

Comment: WebClient is quite old and not advised for new development. Use HttpClient instead.

Comment: i will try it, tks